# Mbedtls_pk_parse_public_key returns 0xfffffff0 with secp256k1 public key

Tags: c, cryptography, mbedtls

Heija everyone,

i think i’m missing something. I generated a private and public key pair with openSSL.
Lines used:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout -out priv_key.pem

openssl ec -in .\priv_key.pem -pubout -out public_key.pem
```

This gives me my key pair. for example this
private key:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIOBYwBnXMgYHsRSv99H4zgtzSClALIcNBN97QbBPNFzHoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAESqPVjJtZ+f7Q5DnhBX/7Xy6CUWi0aEuNbA0JilgF4+T8ruuWl16vrOrI
3dSDDfsafxatLS3BytvtmyOQxye98Q==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAESqPVjJtZ+f7Q5DnhBX/7Xy6CUWi0aEuN
bA0JilgF4+T8ruuWl16vrOrI3dSDDfsafxatLS3BytvtmyOQxye98Q==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Im trying to parse my public key with mbedtls_pk_parse_public_key to an pk_context. My code looks like this:

```
int32_t s32Err = 0; 

mbedtls_pk_init(&pk);

int32_t tempsize = strlen(ecdsaPublic);

s32Err = mbedtls_pk_parse_public_key(&pk, ecdsaPublic, tempsize + 1);
```

my public key (ecdsaPublic) is copy/pasted and formatted like the following:

```
const char* ecdsaPublic =  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
                      "MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAESqPVjJtZ+f7Q5DnhBX/7Xy6CUWi0aEuN\n"
                      "bA0JilgF4+T8ruuWl16vrOrI3dSDDfsafxatLS3BytvtmyOQxye98Q==\n"
                      "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
```

If I now let this run, i get 0xFFFFFFF0 as an error code in s32Err. Sadly I cant find this error code anywhere in the library or im not searching at the right place.

If I try the exact same code with another public key, like this one:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAMALAAUWI7loxRd++n5VG+E6gl1NEC8Z
yQmtyzKEdwwJ+qrC9BSi6f5FmutbJYqu1wR6QitVCEXUrtN1rOBCQ78CAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The parsing returns 0.

Has anyone an idea or a hint?
Is my key generation wrong?

Best wishes and thanks for the help and suggestions!

Marc

Comment: Why `tempsize + 1`?

Comment: I need the whole string with the trailing `\0`. this is why I added the `tempsize + 1`. I added the variable `tempsize` to see the size i pass to the function `mbedtls_pk_parse_public_key`.

Comment: `s32Err` is a signed integer, so it's -16, which is written as `-0x0010` in `mbedtls/bignum.h`. If you build mbedtls natively, you can run `programs/util/strerror -16`. Actually `programs/util/strerror 0xfffffff0` works too.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' you are absolutely right. I add this information to my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: Since I'm using the Zephyr O/S, I have a configuration called `CONFIG_MINIMAL_LIBC_MALLOC_ARENA_SIZE`. This was to small, so I got the error code `0xfffffff0`, which stands for `MBEDTLS_ERR_MPI_ALLOC_FAILED`.

I now doubled my `CONFIG_MINIMAL_LIBC_MALLOC_ARENA_SIZE` and the parsing works as intended.

Edit:
As @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' mentioned sinced s32Err is a signed integer the value `0xfffffff0` represents -16 (-0x0010) which can be found in `mbedtls/bignum.h`.